# Send-MailMessage asking for credentials

Tags: powershell

Send-Mailmessage prompts for my credentials when executed.

I've tried creating a $from variable to provide Powershell with my credentials (technically this is working since I'm only being asked for my password but want it to send the email without authenticating)

```
$from = (Get-ADUser $env:UserName -Properties emailaddress).emailaddress
$To = "example@example.org"

$Subject = "test2"
$Body = "Test2"
$SMTPServer = "10.98.0.20"
$SMTPPort = "25"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -Credential $from
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use -Credential. Just pass -From an address as a string. SMTP doesn’t care. This is happening because you are including -Credential, or your mail server doesn’t accept anonymous relay access.

Comment: The reason I included -credential is because when I ran it without it it gave me an authentication error.  "Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated"

Comment: Is this in a domain? You can use any -From address you want like someemail@mydomain.com. Send to a valid email address. That error message is talking about the account running the script most likely. Not the email address you are trying to email from.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned this in my first post but yea it's my work email so it's trying to authenticate to our exchange server.

Comment: Right, I do this a lot. Your mail server may need to accept anonymous access. I would talk to your exchange admin about checking that for you.

Comment: Do you know if the computer you are scripting on is added to the SMTP server relay?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. I will check with our system engineer.

Comment: No, this machine isn't added to the SMTP server relay. Does it need to be?

Comment: Yes. Once the SMTP server is allowed anonymous access and the computer your script runs on is added to the relay (it’s IP address) then this will work without providing credentials.

Comment: How has this advice worked out for you? Well I hope!

Comment: Going to ask our sys admin to add it and I'll update it here if it works.

Comment: They said allowing anonymous access would be a security issue and the IP relay doesn't apply to our setup.

Comment: Ok. You can read up on storing a secure string object to pass to -Credential. If you use Exchange, the IP relay does apply to your setup. The server your script would run on needs to have it’s IP added to that relay. And allowing server ranges anonymous access inside your domain is a very common configuration. I work at a bank where this is not considered a security issue. There are simple guides for doing this easily found on the web. Anyway, good luck to you!